# UITableView with Right-Side Index, Sections and Searchbar Causes Right-Side Index to Become Squished

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a section, searchbar and a right-hand side index.  Initially, everything works and is drawn properly.  However, when I type into my search bar then click cancel the right index is not redrawn properly. Here's how the index looks after I click the Cancel button.

[image: Squished Index]

Here's normal:

[image: Normal]

[Update]

For some reason I needed to use this method to get my table reloadData to work:

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { ...}

instead of this method:

-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller { ...}

Here is my method:

```
/* Reset Table here
 */
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"\n===searchBarTextDidEndEditing");
    self.isFiltered = NO;
    self.tableView = self.myTableView;

    [self genIndexWithFilter:NO];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

If someone can explain the subtle details, I'll upvote and accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `self.isFiltered` boolean is the variable which controls which set of data is being rendered to screen; either the full list or a refined searched set.

When `-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { ...}` is invoked, the `self.isFiltered` flag is set and you reload the table via. `[self.tableView reloadData];` reloads the table checking the if you are rendering the filtered data or not.

As well when `reloadData` is called it checks to see how many section are to be rendered. If done correctly, you can have something like this...

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(self.isFiltered) //If searching
        return nil; //Return empty section
    else
        return sectionSelectionArray; //Return list of headers
}
```